# Need Quick JavaScript Explanation Involving Functions

Tags: javascript, function

I'm reading a blog reviewing JavaScript, which I am trying to teach myself. I'm still wrapping my head around functions and don't quite understand how this piece of code runs. Can someone please explain it to a me?

Thanks!

```
square = function (a) {
  return a*a;
}
applyOperation = function (f, a) {
  return f(a);
}
applyOperation(square, 10); // 100
```

Comment: note that you can use function.bind to accomplish the same...

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: There are some bad coding practices there. Variables should be declared (so `var square = function (a){...}`) and function declarations should be used in preference to function expressions (so `function square (a){...}`. Of course you can get away with the posted code and some will differ on expressions vs declarations, but when starting out, better to use declarations until you know the difference and when to use expressions.

Comment: I didn't understand where the "f" and "a" came from. And how they functioned.

Answer (score 2):

applyOperation takes in arguments f and a and returns f(a). The f argument is a function and it returns the value of that function given the argument a.

So you call applyOperation(square, 10) which means applyOperation returns square(10) and the square function just returns the argument squared giving you 100.

Answer (score 2):

The `f function` is called the `callback function`. A `callback function` is **a function that is passed to another function**. In your code, the `square function` is the `callback function`.

A `callback function` is generally in the form of:

```
function myFunction (callback, arg){
    // ... some code
    callback(arg);
}

function myOtherFunction(arg){

    // ... some code

    // return something

}

// to invoke the function
myFunction(myOtherFunction, {arg1: 'someStringValue1', arg2: 'someStringValue2'});
```

note that arg object here could have more than two args, and the naming `callback` is a convention. This means the following code is considered valid

```
function myFunction (mysuperrandomfunctionthatwaspassed, arg){
    // ... some code
    mysuperrandomfunctionthatwaspassed(arg);
}
```

although some javascript developers might yell at you if you do not use the word `callback` for a callback function.

---

More reading: [HERE](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) and [HERE](http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/)